# Adobe Flex3: Make a part of Application visible on showing modal popup

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3, popup, adobe

I need to make a part of the application visible on showing a modal popup.

For example:
Say the application has two VBox with vertical layout. There is a `Button` in first `VBox` and when clicked, there is a custom modal popup being shown. By default the whole background of the application remains blur, but I want the second `VBox` to be visible. Is this possible? If yes how can i accomplish this?

Thanks

Anji

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

A modal popup, by definition, disables access to the rest of the application. If you REALLY want to do this, you can create a non-modal popup and manually disable the rest of the application (except the second VBox) on click of the button

Comment: Thanks. Yeah I think I have to go with disabling the rest. But there are quite a lot I have to disable.

Comment: You could put all of them in a container and disable the container

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what Pranav Hosangadi is talking about but according to the [docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00002745.html) the first parameter is the parent of the pop up.

```
PopUpManager.createPopUp(parent, class, modal [, initobj, outsideEvents])
```

> parent A reference to a window to pop-up over.
>
> class A reference to the class of object you want to create.
>
> modal A Boolean value indicating whether the window is modal (true) or
>   not (false).
>
> initobj An object containing initialization properties. This parameter
>   is optional.
>
> outsideEvents A Boolean value indicating whether an event is triggered
>   if the user clicks outside the window (true) or not (false). This
>   parameter is optional.

You may need to use the parent parameter in conjunction with the modal parameter.

If none of this works you can just use modal = false and enable=false the containers that you want to disable.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have tried with your solution, but it is not working. All the components are getting blocked. The `parent` is just reference for the pop-up.

Comment: @The_asMan, a modal popup disables the entire application..trust me, I have tried. The docs aren't always clear.. :)